# new Date().getFullYear() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display a current year in footer and trying to figure out how to get the current year React way?
Is there a way to use new Date().getFullYear()?

Comment: I don't know much about React, but this question seems like it's really asking "how to display something in React?" which makes me feel like you need to use a tutorial.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You need to put the Pure JavaScript inside `{}`. This works for me:

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{(new Date().getFullYear())}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage />, mountNode);
```

The compiled version is:

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      new Date().getFullYear()
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloMessage, null), mountNode);
```

Answer (score 17):

One thing you could do is create a function outside of the render function that gets the year:

```
getYear() {
    return new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

and then insert it into the render function wherever you would like. For instance, you could put it in a `<span>` tag to get the current year in your footer:

```
<span>
   © {this.getYear()} Your Name
</span>
```

Which would produce:

`© 2018 Your Name`

With a well-named function outside of the render method, you can quickly find what the function does and you have the ability to modify it in the future if, say, you want to change the copyright year such as `© 1996 - 2018`, etc.

Answer (score 11):

You could just add a variable `const today = new Date();` then where you want it placed add `<p> {today.getFullYear()} </p>` to pull in the current year.

Answer (score 10):

You Can Copy and Paste this code in your footer components:

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  return (
    <footer>
      <p>
        <small>Copywrite © {year} Name</small>
      </p>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 5):

### exemple using hooks

You can use React `useState` to change value of the variable date to print in the DOM and `useEffect` to show when DOM ready after calling {date} in JSX to print in document loaded:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function Footer() {

    const [date, setDate] = useState();
    
    const getYear = () =>  setDate(new Date().getFullYear())


    useEffect(() => {
        getYear();
    }, [])
  return (
    <>
     &copy; Rogerio Orioli - {date}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Feel free to reference [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It is often more helpful if you include at least a brief explanation along with your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

```
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

then call it;

```
const Copyright = () => {
return (
    <p > © {currentYear} ... </p>
)
}
 export default Copyright;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use one answer and modify it to make it work on react js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export const Footer = () => {
let getYear = () => {
    let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    return currentYear;
};
return (
    <div>
        <footer className="py-5 bg-dark">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <p className="m-0 text-center text-white">
                    Copyright &copy;
                    <span> {getYear()} YourName </span>
                    <br /> Made with ❤️ by YourName 
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old but it has some views.

Here's minimal code to display your starting year, and the current year if it's different, which may be very handy.

```
function DisplayCopyright() {
    const startYear = 2021
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()

    return (
        <> copyright {startYear === currentYear ? date : startYear + "-" + currentYear} </>
    )
}

export default DisplayCopyright
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the current year when the component is mounted, the `useState` is enough:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function Footer() {
  const [currentYear] = useState(() =>  new Date().getFullYear());
  return (
    <>
     &copy; MyWebsite - {currentYear}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you don't need the setter (`setCurrentYear`), then you should be using `useMemo`, not `useState`.

Comment: that's not correct, don't use useMemo Hook if you do not have expensive calculations that are affected by state changes, more details here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo
In the case of useState Hook, you can pass a function which will be executed only on the initial render, more details here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You're right, using useState is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Footer(params) {
 
  const today = new Date()
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  
    return(
        <>
         <footer className="footer">
            <div className="d-sm-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-between">
              <span className="text-muted d-block text-center text-sm-left d-sm-inline-block">Copyright © bootstrapdash.com {year}</span>
              <span className="float-none float-sm-right d-block mt-1 mt-sm-0 text-center"> Free <a href="https://www.bootstrapdash.com/" target="_blank">Bootstrap dashboard template</a> from Bootstrapdash.com</span>
            </div>
          </footer>

        </>
    )
}
export default Footer;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. just copy and paste it anywhere you need it in your React code.

Look at my implementation below where I didn't have to import anything or use any state.

```
{new Date().getFullYear()}

<p className='copyright mt-3'>© All rights reserved. WebsiteName {new Date().getFullYear()}</p>
```